Revoking SSH certificates for per-user cert-authority
In OpenSSH, it's possible to grant access to an entire CA in a single user's authorized keys file using a cert-authority directive (reference). This means I can create my own CA and sign keys for all of my devices, which will work on all of my hosts without me having to update them. However, I can't figure out the revocation story. If I lose access to a device, I want to revoke that device's certificate, and ideally not have to completely create a new CA and resign all my other certificates.
How can I revoke a single certificate when using cert-authority in ~/.ssh/authorized_keys?
I've tried using restrict,command="false" $REVOKED_PUBLIC_KEY, as well as restrict,command="false" $REVOKED_CERTIFICATE, but neither work to prevent a certificate from being accepted while a cert-authority is present. I can't use a per-device principal because then adding a new device requires adding that principal to all of my servers, defeating the purpose of the user CA.
A related but distinct question, How to revoke an ssh certificate (not ssh identity file!), which discusses the system-wide revocation list and doesn't talk about the per-user configuration.
